# DataGridView change cursor selected row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cursor

How can I change cursor arrow to hand. I've 10 columns and I want to change cursor on first column.

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on the `CellMouseEnter` event, you can easily get what you want. Here you have a working code for `DataGridView1` and column 1:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseEnter

    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand 'Different cursor when the mouse is over a cell belonging to column 1
    Else
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if index = firstColumn then

Cursor = Cursors.hand

endif